# Using Rtweet's search_fullarchive in R

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I am trying to use `rtweet`'s `search_fullarchive` using my premium token registered at Twitter Developer. However, I got an error message of:

> Warning: list(message = "Forbidden: Authentication succeeded but account is not authorized to access this resource.", sent = "2019-07-14T14:30:11+00:00", transactionId = "xxxxxxxxxx")

How do I get past this problem? Is there an error in the way i code?

I ensured my token is working well by testing it using `httr`'s `POST` method and it worked completely fine.

I also tested my token using normal search_tweets, and also worked fine.

```
cons_key = "xxx"
cons_sec = "xxx"
acc_tok = "xxx"
acc_sec = "xxx"
app = "abc"

token = rtweet::create_token(app,cons_key,cons_sec,acc_tok,acc_sec)

manutd = search_fullarchive("manchester united",n=500,
fromDate = "201812010000",toDate = "201902010000",
env_name = app,token = token)
```

I expected a tibble dataframe as usually Rtweet's returns. However this is what i received:

> "Warning: list(message = "Forbidden: Authentication succeeded but account is not authorized to access this resource.", sent = "2019-07-14T14:30:11+00:00", transactionId = "xxxxxxxxxx")"
>   data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

Comment: In terms of troubleshooting steps, I would double-check that your app (with cons_key of "xxx") has been connected with the correct developer environment (i.e. "abc") for full archive search over on the Twitter developer dashboard. The error you're seeing is something I would expect to see if there was an issue with the setup there.

Comment: Thanks Andy! It seems that i was confused with the terms used. To help any beginners who might have trouble with the same thing, i'll write down a bit of explanation below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help anyone who might have trouble with the same thing, i'll write down a bit of explanation. Firstly, if you have registered a premium account, go to

To create the token, you need the App Name.

```
token = rtweet::create_token(app_name,cons_key,cons_sec,acc_tok,acc_sec)
```

To do query, you need the environment name.

```
search_fullarchive(q, n = 100, fromDate = NULL, toDate = NULL, env_name = "dev_name", safedir = NULL, parse = TRUE, token = token)
```

Hope it helps beginners or anyone who might have the same troubles.

Comment: I have premium account and I use the same code it not working for me:         
cons_key = "xxx"
cons_sec = "xxx"
acc_tok = "xxx"
acc_sec = "xxx"
app = "HCT_UAE"                                                                                                      
token = rtweet::create_token(app,cons_key,cons_sec,acc_tok,acc_sec)                                                                                                    
hct<-search_fullarchive("HCT_UAE", n = 100, fromDate = "201901010000", toDate = "201911212359", env_name = "dev_hct", safedir = NULL, parse = TRUE, token = token)